# Servlet path is not included in <c:url>

Tags: jsp, url, servlets, jstl

I have a simple Java Webapp (eg. `test`) containing two different SpringMVC application.

My web.xml maps them as:

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>web</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/web/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>restful</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/restful/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Inside the **web** part I'm using "classic" libraries, such as JSTL core.

I don't understand how to avoid JSTL `c:url` tag ignoring the URL pattern.

If I write

```
<c:url value="/browse/"/>
```

the link is rendered as `/test/browse` and not `/test/web/browse`.

What I'm missing?

Thank you

Comment: It is rendered as you specified it. What you said in web.xml doesn't cause any URL-rewriting beyond prepending the content name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<c:url>` does indeed not take servlet path into account. That's your own responsibility. The `<c:url>` only takes [`HttpServletRequest#getContextPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath()) into account.

Either hardcode yourself:

```
<c:url value="/web/browse" />
```

Or inline result of [`HttpServletRequest#getServletPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getServletPath()):

```
<c:url value="${pageContext.request.servletPath}/browse" />
```

Or if you're forwarding, inline result of [`RequestDispatcher#FORWARD_SERVLET_PATH`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#FORWARD_SERVLET_PATH):

```
<c:url value="${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.servlet_path']}/browse" />
```

Wrap if necessary in a custom tag to save boilerplate.

Comment: Yes, I'm already using <c:url value="/web/browse" />, but it can be a real problem if tomorrow I need to modify the mapping by web.xml... the second options seems better, because it is independent by configurations.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the second option dosn't work... I'm using tiles... so if I wrote what you suggest, the link becomes http://localhost:8080/test/WEB-INF/jsp/template/master.jsp/browse ...

Comment: Yes, your anwer works fine... by the way I think that a custom tag is the best idea in terms of "programming-comfort" and reusability of the code... I wrote this question because, in my mind, the absence of this option into standard taglib is very strange... so I thought I was missing something... :)

Comment: JSTL is not a MVC aware taglib. Java EE's MVC framework JSF has however a bunch of tags you're looking for. E.g. `<h:link>` which generates a HTML `<a>` element with the right URL complete with context path and servlet mapping when just specifying the server-side path to the view file.

Comment: My question doesn't depend by MVC: it is just relative to servlet mapping. So it is correct to say that "JSTL in not a servlet-mapping aware lib"... :D Yes, I know JSF is very rich, but (in my mind) I think it is very umconfortable to use if you are not experienced to work with components (like .net, just to provide an example).